# error __init__ when using fatsecret API

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to compile the example.py that fatsecret's developer share in github. but I get an error.

example.py:

```
fs=Fatsecret(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
saved_meals=fs.saved_meals_get()
print saved_meals
result=fs.foods_search("Betty")
print result
```

the API:

```
self.oauth=OAuth1Service(
            name='fatsecret',
            consumer_key=consumer_key,
            consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
            request_token_url='http://www.fatsecret.com/oauth/request_token',
            access_token_url='http://www.fatsecret.com/oauth/access_token',
            authorize_url='http://www.fatsecret.com/oauth/authorize',
            header_auth=False)
```

and get error message like this:

```
 File "example.py", line 11, in <module>
fs=Fatsecret(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
File "C:\Users\Zharfan Akbar\haha\pyfatsecret\fatsecret.py", line 22, in __init__
header_auth=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header_auth'
```

this is the link to the github [Here](https://github.com/trtg/pyfatsecret)

Answer (score 0):

the repo you are using directs you to look at https://github.com/litl/rauth 
to see how OAuth1Service works, and in that repo you can seer that the API changed to
`OAuth1Service(
    name='twitter',
    consumer_key='J8MoJG4bQ9gcmGh8H7XhMg',
    consumer_secret='7WAscbSy65GmiVOvMU5EBYn5z80fhQkcFWSLMJJu4',
    request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
    base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/')`
so you either have to use an older version of OAuth, or update Fatsecret (which is from 6 years ago!)